# Avoid the interception of XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oauth-2.0, xmlhttprequest, websecurity

Is there a way to prevent the interception of XMLHTTPRequests from 3rd party libraries and software? This is a really mighty, but also dangerous feature, because this way every npm dependency can intercept the traffic and steal access tokens.

We were about to implement the owasp recommendation and introduce fingerprint http only cookie. We also moved the access tokens into the memory. After finding out how easy is to intercept each XMLHTTPRequest using something like the snippet below:

```
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
 // do something with the method, url and etc.
 this.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // do something with the response text
  console.log('load: ' + this.responseText);
 });

 return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Isn't that a **huge security risk** with all the external dependencies, that we have in npm? Is there a way to secure that and disallow interceptors and make sure, that the prototype of XMLHttpRequest isn't manipulated?

Comment: There is an ESLint rule for that, `no-extend-native` that could probably be used for this.

Comment: Does it check all the dependencies or only the application code?

Comment: You can run it on any code you want